# How to wrap different components like <ol> with <Typography> when using MDX with MUI (NextJS)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mdxjs

Is there any way to wrap different MDX elements like `ol` or `li` in MUI components to get the MUI theme styles?
The MDX gives out plain HTML without any styles;

```
<ol>
   <li>One</li>
</ol>
```

MUI does have a `<List>` component, but I just want the font to match the

which can be done by wrapping `<li>` in `<Typography>` like

```
<ol>
   <li><Typography>One</Typography></li>
</ol>
```

Right now my MDX component looks like

```
<MDXRemote {...source} components={{
    wrapper: Container, 
    p:Typography
  }} 
/>
```

Is there any weird map method to wrap all items of a list in a custom component or is there an easy way to wrap all text in `<Typography>`? I'm trying to minimize most possible code from `.md` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, solved it using `props`.

```
 <MDXRemote {...source} components={{
            ol: (props:any) => <Typography gutterBottom component="ol">{props.children}</Typography>,
          }} />
```